# OOXML heading not showing

Tags: xml, xslt, ms-word, openxml

I've tried to make a heading with simple word 2016 heading with

```
<w:p>
      <w:bookmarkStart w:id="0" w:name="myAnchor"/>
      <w:r>
        <w:t>
          <xsl:value-of select="//heading"/>
        </w:t>
      </w:r>
      <w:bookmarkEnd w:id="0"/>
    </w:p>
```

And it **looks** like it creates it in the document (denoted by [Headingplaceholder]) , however it does not show up in the navigation pane. I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask this.

[image]

Comment: In order for something to show up in the navigation pane the *paragraph* needs to be formatted with an outline level. You get this automatically if one of Word's built-in heading styles is applied. I recommend you open your result document in Word. Open the STYLES pane or use the STYLES group on the Home tab to apply Heading 1. Save and close the document then view the underlying XML using the Open XML SDK Productivity Tool (free download as part of the Open XML SDK). There you should be able to see the paragraph formatting (w:pPr tag).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this is even though these Headings are default to word document, it is not applied to your document by default. To use these either you should have that style in your template document(document you are adding the heading), in your case "A heading" or you have to grab the Ms word  *.dotx file that has all the default styles and add it your document.

This goes for all the styles you apply to your document(Table styles, etc). It must be present in your document.